# Scraping multiple videos data which is present in the channel using youtube API 3 in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, google-api

I'm trying to **scrape** youtube channel's video data. For that I scraped all the videos url which is present in one particular channel.

With those video Url's trying to fetch the data of each videos using youtube API 3.

I have stored all the videos Url's in a list and passing the list to the function to scrape the data about the video.

I tried to loop all the Url's Im getting only one record. In video id column I'm getting all the ID's in one single row inside the array.

Kindly please do let me know where I went wrong.

```
from apiclient.discovery import build
import argparse
import csv
import unidecode

DEVELOPER_KEY = "XXXXX"
YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME = "youtube"
YOUTUBE_API_VERSION = "v3"

class Something:

    def youtube_video(self,video_id):

        global video_result

        youtube = build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME, YOUTUBE_API_VERSION, developerKey=DEVELOPER_KEY)

        videos = []
        channels = []
        playlists = []
        videoresult = []
        
        #video_id = len(video_id)

        for ids in range(0,len(video_id)):
            video_sample = youtube.videos().list(id=video_id[ids],part="id,snippet").execute()

            #print(video_sample)


            csvFile = open('youtube_video_data_testing1.csv','w')
            csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)
            csvWriter.writerow(["title","videoId","viewCount","likeCount","dislikeCount", "commentCount","favoriteCount"])


            for search_result in video_sample.get("items", []):
                if search_result["kind"] == "youtube#video":

                    title = search_result["snippet"]["title"]
                    title = unidecode.unidecode(title)
                    #ids = search_result["id"]
                    video_response = youtube.videos().list(id=video_id[ids],part="statistics").execute()
                    #print(video_response)
                    #video_id.append(ids)

                    for video_result in video_response.get("items",[]):
                            viewCount = video_result["statistics"]["viewCount"]
                            if 'likeCount' not in video_result["statistics"]:
                                    likeCount = 0
                            else:
                                    likeCount = video_result["statistics"]["likeCount"]
                            if 'dislikeCount' not in video_result["statistics"]:
                                    dislikeCount = 0
                            else:
                                    dislikeCount = video_result["statistics"]["dislikeCount"]
                            if 'commentCount' not in video_result["statistics"]:
                                    commentCount = 0
                            else:
                                    commentCount = video_result["statistics"]["commentCount"]
                            if 'favoriteCount' not in video_result["statistics"]:
                                    favoriteCount = 0
                            else:
                                    favoriteCount = video_result["statistics"]["favoriteCount"]


                    nextPageToken = video_result.get('nextPageToken')
                    while ('nextPageToken' in video_result):
                        nextPage = youtube.videos().list(id=video_id[ids],part="statistics").execute()
                        video_result['items'] = video_result['items'] + nextPage['items']

                    if 'nextPageToken' not in video_result:
                        video_result.pop('nextPageToken', None)
                    else:
                        nextPageToken = video_result['nextPageToken']

                    #videoresult.append(video_result)

                    csvWriter.writerow([title,video_id,viewCount,likeCount,dislikeCount, commentCount,favoriteCount])

            #csvFile.close()

                    return video_result

s = Something()
s.youtube_video(data)
```

I'm getting output like this for one single record.

```
 title,videoId,viewCount,likeCount,dislikeCount,commentCount,favoriteCount

 How to make video marketing work for your business? (Genius Talk Ft.
 Michael Brenner),"['sds0bFbkP9U', 'jHGOtEpKMTg', 'CxkytEeaeoM',
 '7bVblNUuQNU', 'UBQNCokuvsA', 'jkGNEgpwxAw', 'kVt3CtnFD90',
 'zDXX7jA4clg', 'BLD9cMILHCU', 'YPjP7UvRhns', 'E6DDA7PX4qA',
 'L9yYwpowSQE', 'Q5EFZp1Dq30', 'ChxqD72CiL0', 'w6_E2IgSza0',
 'gLrL3rkO5TM', 'MsIu-nIYfds', 'VAr3aV-aFCI', 'WrLnQtqmtaE',
 'xwdBEIammiQ', 'i2PRiIEh-7c', '4E9TmuZZAp4', 'UdKkfuYCAjA',
 'kv6lqSwZJLw', 'S5AfpHHTPVg', 'sGLg0NqAyK0', 'GH5tF063-Og',
 'pDz2ZVp14JU', 'Zn0HQ3kk5mk', 'tvt588IHPSo', '1hvtiFOsb7Y',
 'BKBfBMS9Xuw', 'bIBahCXR10w', 'e0DUIRms_bg', 'VrT7RDh817U',
 'qoqzcYmKn6w', 'sfNC3UaVhNs', 'LbMmS4hLnoo', 'ohwDFePuhlU',
 'VcvkgKElFw0', 'gSMWkdH2rbk', 'cE3hngrYF9I', 'PGoazo0kE9Q',
 'dnWM7Ay67y0', 'fAWRxMhaNsk', 'Q1pEePqeAYc', 'WZs-yZvyhUA',
 'S48cAk_sISs', 'B3uIHj8zxLc', '9OaOo55zbss', 'POtMS7pTR28',
 'Qe1aLETVr9s', 'NWUXJJDukF0', 'NaImKCWyPyU', 'WK-Ou-8dQ4U',
 'm9-RGcr6KN4', '6__glAsOhno', 'rG9Gt_EaN34', 'mXnI2Ojpvyo',
 'EAn-UJZWJY4', 'W-uu717R2gU', 'cnjl7Hl1QF0', 'Oq5SykGHsrA',
 'lpEoiSQVwM4', '_W-f0GOde8Q', 'wLlzgCMJfmw', 'ofNY5Z2zfZc',
 'zHq0S274s1U', 'zVBDHEvyMFs', 'E1-GoEMOm4U', 'HqKJC4267Dc',
 'lYHvaGOJ4jw', 'l8w60VYS0J0', 'Tl-WSyRK7lI', 'DxtL8u2zgqg',
 'OgrurImBf54', 'GLe-k-ct8eA', 'INrHlrSqioU', 'ZmKnf8Ya3jU',
 'afAppKJHBr0', 'kIvdH5mCHeE', 'xlZL_sJGQ5I', '8S8Kon7JsmA',
 'AfM1_jMoBlE', 'FGMzszYrHGI', 'v5rBe6nYyeQ', 'XPnXdn1r724',
 'yQ3ZitZun8s', 'kzLMD5RXBew', 'SPFfYlAMvuI', 'VZDbslni3DQ',
 'Hv397JnNWYc', 'qy7xbEguv8U', 'BGCOfz8M0bQ', 'L1bd16AwvMg',
 'mPrydY0mpfQ', '-V028-D0GkQ', 'hlYsJJAZm7k', '8TGa_RdxegU',
 'HSENz13ZFxo', 'WqwqzJKa7u0', 'l9YVD0bZ4Io', '5fLZXZgsByo',
 'j-4zwpMUsCY', 'PXSXWjfSqY4', 'YUgmIX9V91M', 'fligYEdU34Q',
 'WMtfbEMgxlU', 'fU4Kx1emu9E', 'OwcMbm7qPAQ', 'FAEUCz9Wt2k',
 '00Hn4RKvEhI', 'wrzsudecHQ0', '4aXffNV-UHs', '3ceG3y224VU',
 '1i8KpWev-Ug', 'buvZWcik9hE', '0o4fFgBdQqQ', 'GwQK_fuXU1w',
 'LCbKy0PC9SY', '48rbra_J6W0', 'nS2pPRzb4lg', 'D-2Voa3XmTU',
 'rsxP3FI8kq8', 'ImTiE7_Qz9M', '9_RwsrgDc0A', 'F0OLsdepsVg',
 '78HvcSgNDAQ', 'vnOJPYHIIXc', 'g_rLw2FoRbg', 'sds0bFbkP9U',
 'sds0bFbkP9U']",83,3,0,2,0
```

I need to get data for all the video which I have passed in the list.

My sample list - ['sds0bFbkP9U', 'jHGOtEpKMTg', 'CxkytEeaeoM'] looks like this (All videoID which is available in channel)

Expected output sample for 3 records:

```
 title,videoId,viewCount,likeCount,dislikeCount,commentCount,favoriteCount
    1. How to make video marketing work for your business? (Genius Talk Ft. Michael Brenner),sds0bFbkP9U,83,3,0,2,0
    2. video name 2 , g_rLw2FoRbg, 78,0,9,2
    3. videoname 3 , sds0bFbkP9U,  98,0,23,76
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While trying to write a csv file something went wrong.

```
csv_list = []
filename = 'crashcourse.csv'

with open(filename, 'a') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)


    writer.writerow(('title','videoId','viewCount','likeCount','dislikeCount','commentCount','favoriteCount'))

csv_list.append(['title','videoId','viewCount','likeCount','dislikeCount','commentCount','favoriteCount'])
writer.writerow([title,ids,viewCount,likeCount,dislikeCount, commentCount,favoriteCount])
```

The above code worked for me.